# how to solve missing bitmap stage_empty and missing bitmap stage_fill?

Tags: android, bitmap, samsung-mobile, smartphone

I am unable to access image files and folders of my Android phone.
It pops with

```
Unfortunately App has Stopped.
```

I am using SAMSUNG GALAXY ACE NXT .
Android version : API 18

There comes an error :

After hard rest too it shows following error

```
E:missing bitmap stage_empty(code-1)
E:missing bitmap stage_fill(code-1)
```

Please help me out I have to test some of my apps on which I m working.